# Correct syntax for nested generic arrow function types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a number of TypeScript data types that support a symmetry law, defined like this:

```
type SymmetryLaw<T> = (f: (x: T, y: T>) => T, x: T, y: T) => boolean;
```

Then I can create a symmetry law for number operations (ignoring issues around equality for now):

```
const num_op_symmetry: SymmetryLaw<number> = (f, x, y) =>
  f(x, y) === f(y, x);
```

And one for arrays of numbers if needed:

```
const array_op_symmetry: SymmetryLaw<number[]> = (f, x, y) =>
  f(x, y) === f(y, x);
```

But I'm wondering about generic laws for a generic datatype like arrays. This syntax is wrong:

```
const array_symmetry: SymmetryLaw<Array<T>> = (f, x, y) =>
   // for arrays
```

Is this possible or do I need a different approach?

Comment: I think that would require higher-kinded types, which currently TypeScript doesn't support. Searching for "TypeScript HKT" will lead you down a very deep rabbit hole.